# "command not found" for scripts in ~/bin

Tags: scripts

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 and copied my custom scripts into `~/bin`. Then I made all files in that directory executable, via `chmod`. I double-checked in GUI, and the files are executable.

I checked ~/.profile, and it already contains the following lines (which are NOT commented out):

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" 
fi
```

However, when I try to run a script (in that directory) by typing `my-script-name` in terminal, I get "command not found" error, yet when I type `~/bin/my-script-name`, then it runs properly.

I was able to run custom scripts from `~/bin` directory in this way in 16.04 LTS, but it's not working for me in 17.04. What do I need to do to make this work? Does 17.04 no longer check that directory?

Comment: if a .bash_profile exists; .profile is ignored.  there are a series of files that are run on first login, any logins etc....

Comment: what output of _export | grep $PATH_  you get?

Comment: @Redbob, the output of "export | grep $path" is the following: declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

Comment: @guiverc, I have a file named _.profile_ and a file named _.bashrc_ in _/home/myusername/_, but I do not have a file in that directory called _.bash_profile_.

Comment: @Redbob I think you mean `export | grep '^declare -x PATH='`

Comment: try adding an `export PATH` to your .profile script.  your $PATH may have been modified for the shell running .profile; but didn't get exported to the prior level when it was done...  your 16.04 may have had this later in the file :)

Comment: Check your terminal preferences. You'll see a setting in there that will be something like "Run command as a login shell".  You want that selected.

Comment: @glennjackman There is no need to run Bash as a login shell. OP can just log out and back in. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`~/.profile` is automatically sourced only on login. You have to log out and back in for changes to take effect.

You can also run `source ~/.profile` in a terminal, but the changes will take effect only for that terminal.

When you ran `exec -l bash`, that opened a login shell, but only in that terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere to try running `exec -l bash`, and that fixed the problem within that terminal window, as long as it was open. However, when I closed the window and tried running scripts within a new window, I had the same problem, again.

At that point, I tried rebooting, and the problem is fixed, although I really don't understand why. When I run `export | grep $PATH`, I now get the following:

```
declare -x PATH="/home/myusername/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

So it's possible that running `exec -l bash` and then rebooting may have fixed the problem. I would appreciate any comments or explanation as to whether this was a relevant course of action, or whether it was a random fluke that was fixed by reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your path to execute scripts **in terminal session**
, is preferable to put Path declarations in your ~/.bashrc file.

So, edit your ~/.bashrc file and add at the end of this file, the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

or

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

so everytime you open a terminal session, you will have PATH properly configurated. **You won't have to reboot or relogin your session for it!!**

Comment: This is not going to work: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin/my-script-name`. Items in the PATH need to be dirs.

Comment: it's true, @wjandrea. I corrected it